# Supersede DNS at commandline (rather than directly editing /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf)?

Tags: dns, dhcp, dhclient

I know that I can use my chosen DNS by adding the following line to `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`:

```
$ supersede domain-name-servers 1.1.1.1, 1.0.0.1;
```

I can verify that the correct DNS is being used as follows:

```
$ nmcli dev show | grep DNS
IP4.DNS[1]:        1.1.1.1
IP4.DNS[2]:        1.0.0.1
```

But I'd like to automate the setup of my machine (Ubuntu 18.04), and therefore want to avoid editing `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` directly.  The "simple" solution would be to append to the file:

```
echo "supersede domain-name-servers 1.1.1.1, 1.0.0.1;" | sudo tee -a /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf
```

But this has the disadvantage that the line will be duplicated if the setup script is run twice.  Is there an established way for doing this?

Comment: use `sed` to delete any matching line, then add it. or use `grep` to check for the line, and don't add it if found.

Comment: Thanks, @Patrick--please see my update.  While I was looking for a standard interface, your suggestion does the job.  If you'd like to add it as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.  Thanks for your time.

Comment: This WWW site does not do answers in questions (or "[SOLVED]" and the like).  It _does_ allow one to answer one's own question, in contrast.  Please put your answer _in an answer_.

Comment: @JdeBP Sounds good!  I moved the edit to a standalone answer.  Thanks for clarifying the etiquette.

Answer (score 0):

Per @Patrick's comment, you could do something like this:

```
LINE='supersede domain-name-servers 1.1.1.1, 1.0.0.1;'
FILE=/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf

grep -qF "${LINE}" "${FILE}" || echo ${LINE} | sudo tee --append "${FILE}"
```

I was hoping/expecting that there would be a standard interface through `dhclient` or similar, but if it works, it works.  :-)